# Regular Expression swedish alphabet and whole word

Tags: javascript, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I need help with regular expression. What is allowed is all the:

- swedish aphabet
- number 0-9
- a dot and underscore

What is not allowed:

- all strange characters
- white space
- and the words AND OR NOT OK

I've tried different ways and not getting anywhere. 
in my model i have the following

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?:(?!\b(?i:AND|O[RK]|NOT|FALSE|TRUE)\b)[\wåäöÅÄÖ\._])*$", ErrorMessageResourceName =
```

but im getting a javascript exception ?  problem with the case sensitive i

Unhandled exception at line 660, column 6 in eval code

0x800a139a - JavaScript runtime error: Unexpected quantifier

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**1 & 2**
Swedih alphabet (includes alphabet from the english language, and those you mentioned in your regex), numbers and underscore: `[\wåäöÅÄÖ]`

**3**
Add dot...: `[\wåäöÅÄÖ.]`

**4**
No strange characters in the above character class

**5**
No white space allowed in the above character class

**6**
Specific words through a negative lookahead and adding anchors and quantifiers and flag:

```
@"^(?:(?!\b(?:AND|O[RK]|NOT)\b)[\wåäöÅÄÖ.])*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
```

Comment: Yours is nicer, I never think of doing negative lookahead at the start of a match, feels weird and error-prone for some reason. Maybe that's just a feeling.

Comment: @funkwurm That's fine; I've been using those for a while now and they have never let me down so far :) It's not really fast though, since the above regex checks each character. Two regex might be better here; one to check for the 4 words, then one to validate the characters. Should be faster IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You put the word-boundary `\b` and the negative lookahead inside the character class. This is what I would do and set **ignore case**:

```
^(?:[B-MP-ZåäöÅÄÖ\._]|\bA(?!ND\b)|\bN(?!OT\b)|\bO(?![KR]\b))*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0IUMHkcbsaxtbFmg)

Comment: hi i tried this but how do you set ignore case 

    ^(?:i(?!\b(?:AND|O[RK]|NOT|FALSE|TRUE)\b)[\wåäöÅÄÖ\._])*

![Regular expression visualization](https://www.debuggex.com/i/9TLSO-1SwMHvPUo2.png)

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/9TLSO-1SwMHvPUo2)

Comment: Depends on the environment you work in. In JavaScript it's `/regexhere/gi` where the i at the end sets this. I'm unfamiliar with ASP.NET but you can see @Jerry's answer (which is nicer anyway) mentions `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`. A quick search got me this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx